# Multiplication going wrong

Tags: python, math

I have a lot of data and I want to make an account with them. I calculate x, then y. When I calculate x times y, the count is going wrong, why?? Sounds like something simple, where did I multiply it wrong, please?

[image: the result]

```
z = 0.5

a=0.1
a2= 43

b=0.15
b2 = 40

c = 0.20
c2 = 38

d = 0.25
d2  = 36

e = 0.30
e2 = 34

f= 0.35
f2 = 33

g = 0.40
g2 = 31

h = 0.45
h2 = 30

i = 0.50
i2= 28


um = (1/z**2)*9
print('um=',um)

x = (a/z**2)+(b/z**2)+(c/z**2)+(d/z**2)+(e/z**2)+(f/z**2)+(g/z**2)+(h/z**2)+(i/z**2)
print('x=',(1/um)*x)

y = (a2/z**2)+(b2/z**2)+(c2/z**2)+(d2/z**2)+(e2/z**2)+(f2/z**2)+(g2/z**2)+(h2/z**2)+(i2/z**2)
print('y=',(1/um)*y)

#Final

print(x*y)
```

Comment: Your code says you are printing `x` and `y`, but that's not true.  You're printing `x/um` and `y/um`.  Thus, `x*y` is going to be bigger than that by a factor of `um*um`.

Comment: And why not do `(a+b+c+d+e+f+g)/(z*z)`?  No point in recomputing `z**2` 7 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you did

```
print('x=',(1/um)*x)
```

and

```
print('y=',(1/um)*y)
```

Then, when you multiplied x*y, you actually multiplied different values in comparison to what you printed.

As I understand, for it to be correct you would need something like

```
print(((1/um)*x)*((1/um)*y))
```

or

```
r_um = 1/um
print((r_um*x)*(r_um*y))
```